# Print Textviews and webview from fragment

Tags: android, pdf, printing, webview, textview

I'm using such code for creating pdf from webview

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE); 
PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter("PDF");
printManager.print("PDF", printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```

what should I do, to add to this pdf creation some TextView because I need to add additional fields to my fragment?

Know about itextg, but I need something free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose an option to implement fields as html in webview

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bitmap out of the webview and then draw the textview on the bitmap, using the bitmap canvas.

From there, you can convert the bitmap into a pdf and share the pdf.

Here is the code for converting a webview into a bitmap, and also converting a bitmap into a pdf and then sharing it, asking the user to select its printer app:

```
public static void sharePdfFile(WebView webView, Context context)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = webviewToBitmap( webView );
    PrintedPdfDocument pdf =  bitmapToPdf( bitmap, context );
    File file = pdfToFile( pdf, context );
    shareFile( file,"application/pdf", context );
}

private static void shareFile(File file, String contentType, Context context)
{
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider",
        file);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType(contentType);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "Choose your printer app",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show();
    context.startActivity( shareIntent );
}

private static File pdfToFile(PrintedPdfDocument printedPdfDocument, Context context)
{
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "share.pdf");
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        printedPdfDocument.writeTo(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    printedPdfDocument.close();
    return file;
}


private static PrintedPdfDocument bitmapToPdf(Bitmap bitmap, Context context)
{
    PrintAttributes printAttributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
        .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
        .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
        .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
        .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("1", "label", 300, 300))
        .build();
    PrintedPdfDocument printedPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, printAttributes);
    PdfDocument.Page pdfDocumentPage = printedPdfDocument.startPage(1);
    Canvas pdfCanvas = pdfDocumentPage.getCanvas();
    bitmap = scaleBitmapToHeight(bitmap, pdfCanvas.getHeight());
    pdfCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
    printedPdfDocument.finishPage(pdfDocumentPage);
    return printedPdfDocument;
}

private static Bitmap webviewToBitmap(WebView webView) {
    webView.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            0,
            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
        ),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            0,
            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
        )
    );
    int webViewWidth = webView.getMeasuredWidth();
    int webViewHeight = webView.getMeasuredHeight();
    webView.layout(0,0, webViewWidth, webViewHeight );
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webViewWidth, webViewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, bitmap.getHeight(), new Paint());
    webView.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

private static Bitmap scaleBitmapToHeight(Bitmap bitmap, int maxHeight) {
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    if(height > maxHeight) {
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        float scalePercentage = ((float)maxHeight) / height;
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (width * scalePercentage), maxHeight, false);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```